# ildasm dump compare - only difference is image base

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Given:
Visual Studio 2019

Hi,
I did a `ildasm.exe` on one of my assemblies because `WinMerge` showed that the binaries were different. The only difference is the `Image base`

What could that one difference mean?

[image]

Comment: You really can't compare assemblies at the binary level - they are always different (IIRC, they have some some-of-compile information in them). Microsoft had a tool that did assembly comparison (for industries where proof of identical-ness was legally required (things like casino gaming machines)).  It excluded things that were known to change from the comparison.  I don't know if it was ever released to the public.  Why do you want to do this?  There may be a way to get what you want without doing this comparison

Comment: It means you rebooted the machine between making these two dumps.  The requested image base (not visible) is 0x400000 for .exe files, 0x10000000 for .dll files.  The effective image base (what we can see) is unpredictable due to [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization).  It has no effect whatsoever at runtime.

Comment: If your problem is that WinMerge shows two binaries built with exactly same source code are different, then you can use the deterministic build option. If source code remains the same then the built assemblies will be always the same at byte-by-byte level.